# Store CSS data into a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, arrays

I have a system where the users can manipulate the images. It is very similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/fGJ59/9/show/

My goal is to grab user and positional data (i.e., userid, frame_ID, imageid, width, height, top, left, and z-index) and store it in a database. A new row would have to be inserted into the database for every image in the manipulation frame. I eventually want users to be able to save/edit the images that they have arranged.

So far, I've been able to generate a merged array with all the data using:

```
function getCSS() {

    var id_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("id");
    }).get();

    var width_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("width");
    }).get();

    var height_data = $(".frame div img").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("height");
    }).get();

    var top_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("top");
    }).get();

    var left_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("left");
    }).get();

    var zindex_data = $(".frame div:has(img)").map(function() {
      return $(this).css("z-index");
    }).get();


    var images_array = [];
       $.each(id_data, function (index, value) {
        images_array.push(value);
        images_array.push(width_data[index]);
        images_array.push(height_data[index]);
        images_array.push(top_data[index]);
        images_array.push(left_data[index]);
        images_array.push(zindex_data[index]);
    });

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = images_array;



////////////Post Data


$.post(
    "/save.php",
    images_array,
    function( data ){
        alert("Saved! Received response: " + data);
    }
);

}
```

Post Data currently doesn't seem to do anything.

The array outputs:

```
100,101px,101px,22px,126px,9998,103,96px,96px,152px,30px,9997,104,60px,60px,auto,auto,9996
```

It outputs values of image_id, width, height, top, left, zindex. They repeat without a colon. I don't know if that will make it significantly harder. Note that the default position is not numeric.

Trying to use the suggestion of @Marcin Koziarz, save.php currently contains:

```
<?php
$images_array = $_POST['images_array'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
foreach( $images_array as $image ) {
    // run here query for each image

}
echo "Image data successfully saved.";
?>
```

How can I go about inserting this info into a db?

Comment: Give them all a class, and use `document.getElementsByClass()` to grab all the objects. Then write a loop that copies the CSS properties into an array.

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with your initial approach? Why can't you just get all the individuals style attributes pass them into a form and post it. - Though you're better of having lots of individual rows in the database for each style and have them share the userid collumn value rather than one big array.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, consider using jQuery rather than plain Javascript (it's de facto standard now - many people claim they know jQuery not knowing Javascript).

Action flow would go like this:

1. (JS) Select all elements from container using jQuery's `$("#parent").children()`,
2. (JS) Create an plain JS object containing needed data for each image, user data, etc., using jQuery's `.each()` method, for example:

   ```
   myDataObject = {
       userid: 0,
       images: []
   };
   $("#parent").children().each(function(elem){
       myDataObject.images.push({
           left: $(elem).css("left"),
           top: $(elem).css("top"),
           zindex: $(elem).css("z-index")
       });
   });
   ```
3. (JS) Send object using jQuery's AJAX methods, e.g.

   ```
   $.post(
       "mysite.com/save.php",
       myDataObject,
       function( data ){
           alert("Saved! Received response: " + data);
       }
   );
   ```
4. (PHP) in `save.php` parse POST data (using `$_POST` array) and run SQL queries to add it to database. After completion, `echo` some information which will be displayed to user:

   ```
   <?php
   $images_array = $_POST['images'];
   $userid = $_POST['userid'];
   foreach( $images_array as $image ) {
       // run here query for each image
   }
   echo "Image data successfully saved.";
   ?>
   ```

Comment: *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.* — http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info (The time of jQuery is passing anyway, it provides compatibility and convenience methods, which are becoming increasingly redundant as browsers continue to mature).

Comment: I agree. But there's one issue - legacy browsers won't get anymore mature and one cannot force users to upgrade them. Also, poster seems to lack experience with JS and starting with jQuery might help him do his job.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped guide me to this point. I edited my post to add what I have done so far. Would you mind elaborating on how I can utilize the `$.post()` and php query in this case?